# Whats the differences and options when choosing a cellular module?

Tags: wireless, gsm

I think in most cases you only need to send data in a low rates from a controller to a remote computer when there is no WiFi.

I can see there are some cheap `GSM/GPRS` modules  like `SIM800L` , but lately I see more and more `LTE` modules of companies such as `ublox` .

When an industrial controller needs to send sensors data, what would be the difference between LTE and GSM ?

I also know its a real hassle to use a sim card and get a plan etc - is there a solution for this ?

Are there any good cheap modules for mass production that are recommended ?

Comment: You can lookup the difference between GSM and LTE on your own, hint: GSM is 2G (2nd generation mobile phone network), LTE is 5G (5th generation). You fail to understand that these networks need a **service provider** to keep them running. So you must pay for using them. So the "solution" is to **not use them**. Are there free to use alternatives ? Not that I know. And unfortunately that last sentence makes it into a shopping question.

Comment: There are some technologies like "embedded SIM" that can simplify provisioning if you need hundreds of thousands of the things, but normally you just get a bulk industrial plan and the provider sends you a thousand (or however many you need) SIMs.

Comment: @FakeMoustache did you even bothered to read the whole question? "I failed to understand they need a service provider"? I just wrote it in there - "is there a solution to the sim hassle?" . You say I should go and read about the difference between GSM and LTE ? have you read this at all ? I said- "when you need to send a low rate data - why would you need an LTE for"- that was the actual question you failed to understand it because you are arrogant. Anyway, you are too aggressive, don't hate yourself that much .

Comment: I don't hate myself, I just dislike questions which you could have answered yourself by doing some research. Which is **required** on this site, see help: how to ask a question. And if you google "GSM vs LTE" you will get plenty of hits explaining the differences. **You** want something then **you** should be prepared to research it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LTE and GSM should not matter unless you are moving lots of data.  M2M communications usually involves small data packets.

I would not use the cheap USB sticks.

Multitech has some very good ones. Then there are the Multitech knock offs that are pretty good as well.

Do not think a GPRS modem is similar to a dial up modem. Just because they both use the AT command do not let that fool you into thinking they are similar.

The GPRS modem has a steep learning curve. In the 90s I wrote many modem apps. About 5-10 years ago I wrote a Windows texting app using a GPRS modem.  It took 2 years to get all the bugs out caused by unexpected tower responses or lack there of.  Do not expect the tower to always respond.  The tower will usually respond, many times delayed, and sometimes no response.

Given the high interest in mobile communications is it not strange that there are not more GPRS apps available? Ones that actually work. The reason is because it is difficult.

These are what I have left of the ones I bought from China.  The have the old WaveCom chip.

[image: GPRS Modem]

Comment: I second the "years to get all the bugs out" - there are a lot of things that can happen and the documentation is universally incomplete.

Comment: The problem is that they are too expensive, the LTE modules cost more then 25$ for mass production, how can you price your product like that ?

Comment: Explain **why** $25 is not a realistic price for an LTE module. Companies make and sell these for $25 but you of course know better, please explain why.

Comment: I paid $200 for GSM.  $80 in quantity from China.

Comment: LTE module is basically a cellphone without a screen or keyboard, but made in smaller quantities. $25 seems quite good value for one to me.

Comment: @pjc50 Yes, but not for development.  What will you do with it when (not if) you need support?  How good is the documentation?   My money would be on that it would never make it into service.